# behaviour of timers between 2 consicutive requests in jmeter loadtest

Tags: multithreading, load-testing

I have a thread group with 2 http samplers(Registration and submit button).
I have a scenario like user have to goto registration page and fill the data in form and click on submit button.
I've recorded a script for the same using http proxy server with waiting time using constant timer(5 seconds).
when I trying with single user the sceanario working fine,i.e.user registrations wait for 5seconds and click on submit.
But when I try to do load test with 10 users the requests are not executing sequentially,i.e.some of registrations are executing at a time then submit request executions.. etc as per observations results with viewresultstree listener.

How can I do this scenario for multi users?

Answer (score 0):

This is **expected** behaviour as JMeter Threads (virtual users) are totally independent from each other.

JMeter acts as follows:

1. It launches threads defined in the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) within the bounds of ramp-up period
2. Threads start executing [Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to [Logic Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))
3. When there are no more samplers to execute and/or loops to iterate - thread is being shut down.

So **each** thread will execute first Registration then Submit. Depending on your ramp-up period value you might run into situation when some users are executing "Registration" and some are doing "Submit" causing mess in your results.

You can do one of the following:

1. Add [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function to your samplers names. At least you won't be confused with the order

   [image: JMeter execution order]
2. Play with your ramp-up period so there would be only 2 maximum online users
3. Add [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) to your request. This way all 10 users will simultaneously execute all the requests in the timer's scope.